# Group list of items randomly, but some items cannot be in same group

Tags: python

I have a list of names that I want to put into n-number of groups. I can do that easily. However, my issue is, that some of the items cannot be grouped together no matter what. Is there a simple solution to this ?

This is how I do it now:

```
import random

name_list = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7"]
n = 2

random.seed(4)
random.shuffle(name_list)

test = [name_list[i:i + n] for i in xrange(0, len(name_list), n)]

print(test)
```

So from this, I will get 4 groups, randomly shuffled, with only 1 in the last group (that is okay). However, let's say that `Item1` and `Item5` can't end up together. How would I dot that ?

Comment: Before calculating your random, you could check if `Item1` is already placed, and if yes only find a random in the other possible groups?

Comment: When solving a problem like this, I suggest turning off the computer and getting a pen and paper. Write **in words** what steps you need to take to solve the problem. Once you have a clear idea of these steps then come back to your computer and try to translate them into Python. Along the way you will find steps that need more detail. So then you rinse and repeat.

Comment: It's not going to be as simple as your original code. You'll need to write a loop that picks a random target group. If the target already contains an item that the current item can't be paired with, repeat the random selection.

Comment: Can there be multiple items that an item can't be paired up with? A simple algorithm like that might result in total starvation if every bucket contains one of them. You might need to go to a complex constraint fitting algorithm.

Comment: If your question is "how would I do that", you can always loop through the shuffled items and construct the groups- one element at a time, after performing the check. If you were looking for a more Pythonic (elegant) way, that is a different question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Here we get groups or "chunks" for randomly distributed items.

**Given**

```
import random
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit


random.seed(4)
n = 2
name_list = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7"]
blacklist = ["Item1", "Item5"]
```

**Code**

```
def get_random_groups(lst, size=2, blacklist=None):
    """Return distributed items among `m` groups of lists."""
    if blacklist is None:
        blacklist = []

    # Compute number of chunks
    length = (len(lst))
    if length % 2 == 0:
        m = length//size
    else:
        m = (length+1)//size

    # Edge cases
    if len(blacklist) > m:
        raise ValueError("Black-list is too long.  Must be < number of chunks.")
    if not set(blacklist).issubset(set(lst)):
        raise ValueError("Black-list is not a subset of the main list.")

    # Resize list
    remnant_list = list(set(lst) - set(blacklist))
    random.shuffle(remnant_list)

    # Build chunks and distribute (blacklist first)
    chunks = [list(c) for c in mit.distribute(m, blacklist)]
    random.shuffle(chunks)

    for chunk in chunks[:]:
        while len(chunk) < size:
            try:
                chunk += [remnant_list.pop(-1)]
            except IndexError:
                return chunks
```

**Demo**

```
# Without blacklist
get_random_groups(name_list, size=n)
# Out: [['Item5', 'Item1'], ['Item3', 'Item6'], ['Item7', 'Item2'], ['Item4']]

# With blacklist
get_random_groups(name_list, size=n, blacklist=blacklist)
# [['Item2', 'Item6'], ['Item1', 'Item3'], ['Item5', 'Item7'], ['Item4']]

# Invalid blacklist
blacklist = "Item1 Item3 Item 5 Item6 Item7".split()  
get_random_groups(name_list, size=n, blacklist=blacklist)
# ValueError: Blacklist is too long.  Must be < number of chunks.

# Invalid blacklist
blacklist = "Item1 Item9".split()  
get_random_groups(name_list, size=n, blacklist=blacklist)
# ValueError("Black-list is not a subset of the main list.")
```

---

**Details**

- The number of chunks is computed based on lists of even or odd length.
- Edge cases are tested (optional).
- Items in the `blacklist` will be distributed among chunks first.  Therefore, those items must be removed from the list of remaining elements (`remnant_list`).
- [`more_itertools.distribute`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distribute) is a third-party tool that facilitates *chunking* and *distributing items* among `m` number of chunks.  You can optionally implement your own algorithms to accomplish these two tasks.
- A random remnant item is added to a shuffled chunk unless the `size` of the chunk is satisfied.  This double shuffling ensure items are placed randomly.